# How to get datetime from SharePoint 2007 web services

Tags: 2007, web-services

How can we get a datetime value of a listitem from SharePoint 2007 using web services? (so we cannot use SharePoint server-side object model or CSOM). 
The site could use any regional settings / datetime formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this article:
http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/07/14/more-sharepoint-list-web-service-calls/

From returned XML, you must take this node:
 **ows_Created=“2007-07-13 11:50:10“**